# XSLT IF evaluation rules

Tags: xpath, xslt-2.0

From the XML file :

```
    <store >
      <tools>
        <tool IDT="T1">
          <container>B1</container>
          <container>B2</container>
        </tool>
        <tool IDT="T2">
          <container>B1</container>
        </tool>
        <tool IDT="T3">
          <container>B2</container>
        </tool>
      </tools>
      <boxes>
        <box IDB="B1" height="10" width="20" length="30" weight="4"/>
        <box IDB="B2" height="5" width="40" length="30" weight="2"/>
      </boxes>
    </store>
```

I try to display for each box the list of tools that go into each box. For that, I wrote the following XSL:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
                    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
                    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
                    xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
      <xsl:output 
         method="html"
         encoding="UTF-8"
         doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
         doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"
        indent="yes" />
      <xsl:template match="/">
      <html>
        <head>
          <title>Boxes contents</title>
          <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
        </head>
        <body>
          <h1>Boxes contents</h1>
          <ul>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="/store/boxes/box" /> 
          </ul>
        </body>
      </html>
      </xsl:template>
      <xsl:template match="box" >
        <li><xsl:text>Box </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="@ID"/>
            <xsl:text>contains the following tools : </xsl:text>
        </li>
        <xsl:call-template name="findTools" >
          <xsl:with-param name="currentBOX"  select="@IDB"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:template>

      <xsl:template name="findTools" >
         <xsl:param name="currentBOX" />
         <xsl:for-each select="/store/tools/tool/container" >
            <xsl:if test="container = $currentBOX" >
               <br><xsl:value-of select="@IDT"/></br>
            </xsl:if>
         </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

When I do it, I never see the tools. In debug under OXYGEN, I see that the IF is never true. I do not understand why? I start in XPath and XSLT, thanks for your help

Answer (score 3):

You already are at a `<container>` element inside the `<xsl:for-each>`. There are no children, so selecting *another* `<container>` inside the `<xsl:if>` won't return anything.

You mean to execute your check from the `<tool>` node.

```
<xsl:for-each select="/store/tools/tool">
    <xsl:if test="container = $currentBOX">
        <xsl:value-of select="@IDT"/><br />
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

which is easier written as

```
<xsl:for-each select="/store/tools/tool[container = $currentBOX]">
   <xsl:value-of select="@IDT"/><br />
</xsl:for-each>
```

---

Overall a more straight-forward way to write the two templates would be this:

```
<xsl:template match="box">
    <li>
        <xsl:text>Box </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="@ID"/>
        <xsl:text>contains the following tools : </xsl:text>
    </li>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/store/tools/tool[container = current()/@IDB]" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="tool">
    <xsl:value-of select="@IDT"/><br />
</xsl:template>
```

And alternatively you can use an `<xsl:key>` to index `<tool>` elements by their `<container>` value:

```
<xsl:key name="kToolByContainer" match="/store/tools/tool" use="container" />

<xsl:template match="box">
    <li>
        <xsl:text>Box </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="@ID"/>
        <xsl:text>contains the following tools : </xsl:text>
    </li>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('kToolByContainer', @IDB)" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="tool">
    <xsl:value-of select="@IDT"/><br />
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer which allowed me to discover new methods to write my piece of XSLT code. However, none of the proposed solutions returns the value of the @IDT attributes in the HTML page! With the OXYGEN debugger, I see that the <xsl: value-of /> statement is executed, but nothing is written in the HTML feed?

Comment: Thanks, I should have seen it :-(, that proves that I still have a lot to learn in XSLT and Xpath!